# how to upload a zip file in prime faces

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, websphere-8

P:file upload is not working properly, it freezes out, if I try to upload zip file. What could I do resolve this issue.But It works perfectly fine if file of less size are uploaded. I am using prime faces 3.5 and jsf2 and was8 server

Comment: Did you add filter to web.xml: **<filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>**, ref: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13471199/filedownload-and-fileupload-jsf-primefaces-not-working

Comment: @RongNK: read the question once again. If the file upload filter wasn't registered, the OP would not be able to upload *any* file at all. This totally contradicts the statement *"But It works perfectly fine if file of less size are uploaded"*.

Comment: What size of file for the "ok" upload and the "not ok" upload?

Comment: @AlexandreLavoie: I have specified threshold parameter in web.xml 51200. I am able upload file up to 250kb document and more than that. same document in zip file uploaded is not working, file disappears on UI after uploading and on Websphere8 console I see this statement com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper destroy SRVE0248I: Requests are currently being processed. Waiting up to 60 seconds before forcing filter destroy.

Comment: I have the same problem fileupload works fine on all types except when trying to upload zip file. I am using advanced mode and upload listener is not being invoked when allowed file type is zip.