# How to avoid hard code full path in Paths#get method

Tags: java, primefaces

I want to save a copy of Primefaces `UploadedFile` to my project directory. I have been searching the internet for the solution, what I have found is using `Paths#get` method. The example given in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14214223/4541141) answer is `Paths.get("/path/to/uploads");`, the problem is, where is the exact path of `/path/to/uploads`? I can't find it. I mean where should I create the path `/path/to/uploads`? Under my project directory? but which folder? I solve this issue temporary by hard coding the full path like `Paths.get("C:/uploads/");`

Comment: Never ever save an uploaded file to your project directory... With a redeploy it is all gone. Save it outside the webapp... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4358493/j2ee-primefaces-fileupload-file-saving-destination and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14211843/how-to-save-uploaded-file-in-jsf

Comment: And the Paths string starts with a / so it is abdolute to the current filesystem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRealPath("/")` will return you the current installation directory of your project.

And as @Kukeltje suggested, never ever save an uploaded file to your project directory, ... save it outside the webapps or even outside your container.

Therefore create a directory outsite your container (where you want to place your uploaded copies) and append `../` to the above path for each back step.

Say, if your application is deployed at `D:/Tools/Tomcat7/webapps/your-application-name` (e.g. on Windows using Tomcat) and you want to save copies to `D:/Tools/uploads` then following will give you required file path:

```
String uploadsFilePath = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext()
    .getRealPath("../../../uploads");
```

Use it with the `Paths.get(uploadsFilePath)` and develop your download logic (I am not sure which library you are using for the `Paths` class).

Comment: I almost always suggest to use absolute paths. Then you are never dependent on the installation location. I know the Q is about avoiding 'absolute' paths, but the absolute paths should be made configurable. You are now dependent on a **hard coded** relative path...

Comment: Yeah, it is relative path but not **hard coded**, as `FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRealPath("/")` will return the application's dynamic installation directory according to the `OS`. And for the `uploads` folder, it could also be created from code (if that doesn't exist).

Answer (score 0):

How about `getClassLoader().getResource(Path/to/file)`

So like

```
MyClass.class.getResource(bla/bla)
```

Which are now nested in `src/resources`

Like this You are system independent 
**#profit**

Answer (score 0):

You have several options:

1. For very quick development, you can use a hardcoded path, but be sure that it exists in your SUT (system under test).
2. You can define it as a static final string in your module, but this means that each time you want to change that path, you will need to recompile...
3. You can read that value from a property/config file.

There are more options (like using the registry if you are on Windows, or using an environment variable).